# Prove that every positive rational number can be expressed as a quotient of products of numbers of the form ${n\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

> Prove that every positive rational number can be expressed as a quotient of products of numbers of the form ${n\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}$

Below is my attempt. I'm not sure how to express fractions such as $(2k)/(2k+1)$ in the desired form.

Let $a/b$ be a positive rational number. Note that we can swap the numerator and denominator in the quotient of products of numbers of the form ${n\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ that equals $a/b$ to write $b/a$ in the desired form (*). By this fact and the fact that $1 = {1\choose \lfloor 1/2\rfloor}$, we may assume WLOG that $a<b$. Observe that $a/b = a/(a+1)\cdot (a+1)/(a+2)\cdots (b-1)/b,$ so it suffices to prove the claim for fractions of the form $a/(a+1)$. We first deal with the case of fractions of the form $(2k+1)/(2k+2)$. Note that ${2k+1\choose k}/{2k+2\choose k+1} = (2k+1)!/(k!(k+1)!)\cdot (k+1)!^2/(2k+2)! = (k+1)/(2k+2) = 1/2$ and that ${2k\choose k}/{2k+1\choose k} = (2k)!/(k!)^2 \cdot (k!(k+1)!)/(2k+1)! = (k+1)/(2k+1).$ Then ${2k+1\choose k}/{2k\choose k}\cdot {2k+1\choose k}/{2k+2\choose k+1} = (2k+1)/(2k+2),$ as desired. Now we deal with the case of fractions of the form $(2k)/(2k+1).$  I'm not sure how to deal with this case. As a specific example, one can try expressing $6/7$ in the desired form. I get $6 = {3\choose 2}/{2\choose 1}\cdot {4\choose 2}/{3\choose 2}\cdot {6\choose 3}/{5\choose 2}$, but I'm not sure how to get $1/7$.

It may be useful to consider cases where n is prime.

Comment: To get $\frac 17$ choose $n=3$ and $n=4$ in the numerator, and $n=9$ in the denominator.  Alternatively, take $n=4$ twice in the numerator, and $n=10$ in the denominator.

Comment: Inductively, you can get every $\frac 1p$ for $p$ prime:  note that $p$ first appears as a divisor when $n=p$, and then it appears to the first power.  Then the symbol attached to $n$ is of the form $p$ times a product of smaller primes, which we already know we can get.  Having achieved $\frac 1p$ we can get everything.

Comment: Note:  my examples, arrived at by simple search, were not designed according to the inductive scheme.  To do $\frac 17$ according to the scheme,  We first note that $\gamma_7=35$ is the first time $7$ appears as a divisor (where $\gamma_n=\binom {n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$).  Since we have $5=\frac {\gamma_5}{\gamma_2}$ we get another expression for $\frac 17$.

Comment: Note:  you should edit your post to indicate which contest this is taken from (this holds for all the questions you pose).  I trust the contest has closed?

Answer (score 0):

OP has everything that they need, and just need to push through the algebra.
OP's idea of chaining together $\frac{k+1}{k}$ terms to get $ \frac{a}{b}$ is a good idea, but hard to execute on. It's easier to get $a$ directly.

1. (From OP) We can get $ \frac{ k+1}{2k+1}$
2. (From OP) We can get $ \frac {1}{2}$
3. Show that we can get $1$
4. Prove by strong induction that we can get any integer $m$.

   - $m = 2k$, take $ k \div \frac{1}{2}$.
   - $m = 2k+1$, take $ (k+1) \div \frac{ k+1}{2k+1}$.
5. Conclude that we can get any positive rational $ \frac{a}{b}$.